# How to resolve references in Unmarshaled struct

Tags: json, go

I have two json files that I unmarshal in Go.

The first one includes a certain type of object that is referenced by ID in the second set.

```
// Foo
{
  "id": 5,
  "key": "value"
}
```

and

```
// Bar
{
  "name": "bar",
  "fooReferenceId": 5
}
```

I want to end up with a `struct` like

```
type Bar struct {
  Name string
  Foo *Foo
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this directly similar to how we provide `json:"..."` key resolver?

Something like

```
type Bar struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Foo  *Foo   resolveFooById(`json:"fooReferenceId"`)
}
```

Comment: Sure, if you write it.

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Well, it's obviously not simply `Foo *Foo resolveFooById(json:"fooReferenceId")` and I'm missing the necessary keywords to find a solution on google - which is why I was turning to SO for some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a custom unmarshaler like the example at the bottom of this post:

http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/

For your example this would look like:

```
func (b *Bar) UnmarshalJSON(input []byte) error {
    type Alias Bar
    aux := &struct {
        FooReferenceID int `json:"fooReferenceId"`
        *Alias
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(b),
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(input, &aux); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for index, foo := range foos {
        if foo.ID == aux.FooReferenceID {
            b.Foo = &foos[index]
            break
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Full executable example here:

https://play.golang.org/p/SCpsVCgnSSK

Comment: Thanks a lot Iain, exactly the info I was missing. Much appreciated!